# Jekyll + GitHub works on local but empty page on https://username.github.io

Tags: github, jekyll

Hi I'm a newbie on jekyll.
I have a problem with building my github blog using jekyll.
I succeeded building jekyll blog on my local like below image.

[works in local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WI7po.png)

And I did some git works to my github repository. https://github.com/ooroogi/ooroogi.github.io

I thought I followed all the steps in the guide maybe.
But All I can see is only blank page.
https://ooroogi.github.io/

So I digged lots of another working sites to solve this problem, but I can't find what makes difference.

I Hope anyone of you can help my issue.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub Pages only supports certain themes out-of-the-box: 
https://pages.github.com/versions/

To use custom themes you need to use their [`remote_theme` feature](https://github.com/benbalter/jekyll-remote-theme)

Comment: Thanks.
I decided using another theme.
With original theme, I checked my github page working.